# Les raisonnements optimistes sont plus fréquents que ceux pessimistes

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord, démonstratifs, ellipse

L'utilisation de *ceux* pour remplacer *raisonnements* est-elle grammaticalement correcte dans cette phrase :

> Les raisonnements optimistes sont plus fréquents que ceux pessimistes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is not grammatical. You should use an article together with an adjective, omitting the noun, to avoid repetition:

> Les raisonnements optimistes sont plus fréquents que les pessimistes.
>
> Il y a plus de bateaux bleus que de rouges.

It's possible to use a demonstrative pronoun, but only if the characterization is:

- introduced by a preposition

  > Les bateaux à voile bleue sont plus rapides que ceux à voile rouge.
- a subordinate clause

  > Nos salades sont plus fraîches que celles que tu as apportées.
- or, in some cases, a past participle

  > Les jours à venir s'annoncent meilleurs que ceux passés.

Comment: Ah, j'aurais dû répondre en français.

Comment: Ces gens bilingues, c'est fou, ils écrivent anglais sans s'en rendre compte... :)

Answer (score 3):

Non. Les [pronoms démonstratifs](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/demonstrative-pronouns/) doivent être utilisés dans une de ces constructions particulières :

1. avec un suffixe *-ci* ou *-là*
2. avant une phrase prépositionnelle
3. avec un pronom relatif

Dans votre exemple, seul le numéro 3 est possible :

> Les raisonnements optimistes sont plus fréquents que ceux qui sont pessimistes.

Ou bien, on peut le dire autrement :

> Les raisonnements optimistes sont plus fréquents que les pessimistes.